# Filtering Innapropriate Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, chatroom

I have a chatroom that filters inappropriate content near perfectly using an array called blackList (an array of inappropriate words) and iterates through that and replaces inappropriate words with ****'s. However, when it comes across a word like "classy", it stars-out the third through fifth letter. How do I stop this and related problems? Thanks, and here is my code:

```
- (void)displayChatMessage:(NSString*)message fromUser:(NSString*)userName {

    for(int i =0 ;i< blackList.count;i++)
    {
         NSMutableString* stars = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
         for(int j = 0 ; j <[[blackList objectAtIndex:i] length];j++)
             [stars appendString:@"*"];
         message = [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString*)[blackList objectAtIndex:i] withString:@"***"];
     }







       [chat appendTextAfterLinebreak:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", userName, message]];
      [chat scrollToBottom:chat];




     }
```

Comment: Read comments on my answer in your previous question :)

Comment: Try using a regex. e.g. use a regex would look like "\sass\s". This will just return a positive flag for " ass " not classy.

Comment: This is your fifth question on the same topic. Are you sure you can't just edit one of your older questions?